# Spring Rest API User Authentication for One Time

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

I am making Rest API. I have to do one time user authentication. They won't make any other request after login to api. I am using Spring Security for MVC authentication.

```
else if(!customerWithEmail.getPassword().equals(passwordEncoder.encode(password))){
        map.put("ERROR CODE", "04 - Wrong Password");
        //Doesnt work for sure.
        //TODO email password auth.
        return map;
    }
```

I have problem with user and password auth. I am using BCrypt with UserDetails in other modules.

Our clients has static IP address and they can't login anywhere but recorded IP address in DB. But email password check will be good for future.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class ApiController {

@Autowired
private CustomerDao customerDao;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Map customerLogin(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email, @RequestParam(value = "password") String password,
                  HttpServletRequest request) {

    Map map = new HashMap();
    try {

        String customerIpAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        Customer customerWithEmail = customerDao.getUserByEmail(email);
        Customer customerWithIpAddress = customerDao.getUserByIpAddress(customerIpAddress);


        if (customerWithEmail == null) {
            map.put("ERROR CODE", "01 - User Not Found");
            return map;
        } else if (customerWithIpAddress == null) {
            map.put("ERROR CODE", "02 - IP Address Not Found");
            return map;
        } else if (!customerWithEmail.equals(customerWithIpAddress)) {
            map.put("ERROR CODE", "03 - User and IP Address Does Not Match");
            return map;
        }else if(!customerWithEmail.getPassword().equals(passwordEncoder.encode(password))){
            map.put("ERROR CODE", "04 - Wrong Password");
            //Doesnt work for sure.
            //TODO email password auth.
            return map;
        }
        else {
            map.put("Email", customerWithEmail.getEmail());
            map.put("Name", customerWithEmail.getName());
            map.put("Surname", customerWithEmail.getSurname());
            map.put("Company", customerWithEmail.getCompanyName());
            return map;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        map.put("ERROR CODE", "05 - See Details");
        map.put("Error", e.toString());
        return map;
    }

}
}
```

Is my business logic true? I thing isn't.

Comment: Why you cant check if username and password are match?

Comment: I take password parameter but this is `customerWithEmail.getPassword().equals(passwordEncoder.encode(password))` doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `encode` and `equals` since BCrypt is using a random salt. Instead:

```java
if (!passwordEncoder.matches(password, customerWithEmail.getPassword()))
```